# iOS Button does not display text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need some help please.
I created a button use Xcode 11.3.1 + OC.In iOS12,it display text only when i touch,below is my code

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn setTitle:@"test string" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setTitleColor:UIColor.blueColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
btn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Before clicking (iOS 12):

[image: this screenshot is before i click in iOS 12]

After clicking (iOS 12):

[image: the screenshot is after i click in iOS 12]

Before clicking (iOS 13):

[image: the screenshot is before i click in iOS 13]

GMT+8 2020-03-17 update:
The same problem was found in the UISegmentedControl and placeholders of UITextField，maybe problem is in UIControl?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It seems nothing is wrong with your code. Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: thanks for your reply.i edited my question and add screenshot

Comment: Interesting, a white text color while you have a blue color in your code? Are you sure that that is what you are running in your simulator?

Comment: Yes,and this bug only appears in iOS12.

Comment: this is just a guess, have you tried moving the frame init after instance initialisation?

Comment: Can you paste the whole `ViewController` code so that we can check it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.All my code is on it,after testing, I found that this problem should be caused by other code in the current project，I check the category now